# Nextjs build in standalone mode hangs with Turborepo (> v1.2.6) and not exit from Gitlab CI pipeline task

Tags: next.js, gitlab, gitlab-ci, pnpm, turborepo

I have project with a monorepo on pnpm workspaces and turborepo to manage monorepo scripts.

All the single projects works as expected, they are nextjs projects.
When i upgraded turborepo from the 1.2.6 to the 1.4.0 version and when i run the build script on a gitlab ci, the build task succeeded, but the pipeline keep stuck.

[image: build output]

I run the script in this way on the pipeline

> .gitlab-ci.yml

```
.build-dashboard:
  image: gitlab.****.it:4567/.../node-pnpm
  stage: build
  script:
    - pnpm build:dashboard
```

> package.json

```
....
scripts: {
    "build:dashboard": "turbo run build --filter=...@project/dashboard && exit 0"
}
...
```

i try to force the exit using exit 0, but without success (with turobrepo > 1.2.6).

Any suggestions on that ?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

After many attempt i get an additional log messagge

```
Attempting to remove file /builds/.../....-user-interface/node_modules/.cache/turbo/a9f0a39c2d3de111/apps/main/.next/standalone/node_modules/.pnpm/supports-color@7.2.0/node_modules/has-flag; a subdirectory is required
```

Comment: Do you mind sharing `build` script of `@project/dashboard`? Does it still get stuck if you replace that `build` script with e.g. `echo test`?

Comment: The `build` script is a simple `next build`. I tried with an `echo test` script with the same turbo configuration and it works. With this elements i suppose that nextjs build for some reason does not emit the exit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed [here](https://github.com/vercel/turborepo/issues/1481)  the problem whas related to turborepo with next build in standalone mode.

Install `"turbo": "1.4.4-canary.0"` solve the issue.